# Download PhotoAlbum from Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook

I have an photo album that I have uploaded to facebook before , and I need to download it back , but it's too boring to download it one by one

so can any one tell me if there is any ready API to do that , or can I make it my self and how can I make it ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8442/ to download the albums. Worked like a charm for me in firefox.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.Sabeen Malik

Comment: whats the name of the addon? this page https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8442/ doesnt works anymore :s